# Karma Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm getting this error from Karma when trying to run `grunt karma:debug`:

```
11 11 2017 00:00:00.000:INFO [Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA with id 99999999
Chrome 61.0.0000 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  at http://localhost:9876/context.html
Chrome 61.0.0000 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  at http://localhost:9876/context.html
Chrome 61.0.0000 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (1.035 secs / 0 secs)
```

What can be the cause? it started to happen overnight after a commit with some big JSON files. If I go back to the commit without the JSON files, the command starts working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
config.set({
    ...
    files: [
        ...
        { pattern: "path/to/fixtures/**/*.json" },
        ...
    ]
```

That line makes Karma include the JSON files inside the HTML page, and seems it had trouble with the amount of JSON files I was adding. The solution is to tell Karma to not include those files inside the HTML but to serve them as a WebServer:

```
config.set({
    ...
    files: [
        ...
        { pattern: "path/to/fixtures/**/*.json", included: false },
        ...
    ]
```

Relevant documentation is [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html):

```
included
Type. Boolean
Default. true
Description. Should the files be included in the browser using
             <script> tag? Use false if you want to load them manually,
             eg. using Require.js.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have assigned component variable only once, ideally in top **beforeEach** only.

**component = fixture.componentInstance** - This should not be given in each describe.